# Typescript: Remove the intersection type from main type

Tags: typescript

I new to Typescript and stuck on this problem.
So, I have a type defined as:

```
type MainType = Node & {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  notifications: number
}
```

I want a type with does not contain `Node` type.

```
//Expected type
 {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  notifications: number
 }


// I tried using Exclude, but it returns never
type SecondaryType = Exclude<MainType, Node>

//I tried using Omit, but that doesn't allow me to pass Node
type SecondaryType = Omit<MainType, Node>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to omit all the keys from `Node` type:

```
type SecondaryType = Omit<MainType, keyof Node>
```

Check this [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAQQHYHswAsYCcAq14C8cA3qHOXAEYA2AhjbQFxxICuAtpdmRQGYopmAZzBYAlkgDmoAL6hQkWHACytCXiVFkaTLnxwAZCR5iAJsNETJAbh5Ja7GBfFTbIcqjBjeYgMa0vFCQhZjZObhA5EAV9AHUxDBRWMAA5FFNCOAB5dgSAHlV1fAAaOABrGAgUXkRPXQ0YAD55EGoYMDgcGBE4ZnjE5LSMuCJSaMigA)